# Variables are null in included files

Tags: php

For some reason the file I'm including into my PHP script doesn't recognize any of the variables I've defined up until that point:

Main file:

```
var_dump($recipients); // produces proper output
require DOCROOT. "Mail/add_message.php";
```

Included file:

```
<?
var_dump($recipients); // returns NULL
exit();
```

What are the possible reasons for this happening?

Comment: Global variables are evil. I would suggest re-organizing your code (and potentially using OOP with class autoloading) to prevent include hell.

Comment: Try doing `var_dump(get_defined_vars())` in your second file and see what it shows.

Answer (score 0):

1. -- use $_GET `include(http://URL.com?var=$var)`
2. -- if you are using symfony -- include_component()

Answer (score 0):

I just took the script in the second file, grouped it as a function (the required variables being the parameters of the function) and put it in my functions library. It works fine now!